# What is the maximum amount of data that can be passed through an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-framework

I would like to send a large amount of data from one app to another.  The way I plan to do it is through the Intent.putExtras(String name, byte[] value) method.

Would using a Bundle make a difference?

Btw, let's just say for my case, transferring data via the filesystem is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Q: What are your requirements? (implicit question: why is a sane approach like using the filesystem out-of-bounds?)

Comment: Transferring data via filesystem is your best option here, I think.  Could you give us more reasoning as to why not filesystem?  Also what is your data structure like that you're trying to pass?

Comment: The main requirement is security.  I don't want to needlessly copy sensitive data to the filesystem.  I know it's not fully secure but letting the Android framework transfer the data for me is at least one layer of security (instead of saving the file explicitly to disk).  I was kind of hoping for a low-hanging fruit here that can be implemented pretty quickly...

Answer (score 1):

intent is designed to carry message, not data(about 1MB and over that it will fails). how about content provider ?